# 'DECFLOAT' error in db2

Tags: db2, toad-scripting

> Lookup Error - DB2 Database Error: ERROR [22018] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0420N  Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "DECFLOAT".

Query-----

```
SELECT 
   MSISDN,
   CONTRNO,
   TRANSDATE,
   TARIFF_GROUP,
   ACT_DURATION,
   BILLTEXT,
   GROSS_AMOUNT,
   CASE
       WHEN TARIFF_GROUP IN('PAG2')
       THEN DECIMAL((DECIMAL(ACT_DURATION,10,4)/10),20,4)*0.01
       ELSE 'CHECK'
   END RA_RATE
FROM HISTCALLS
WHERE call_type IN (50,
                    54)
  AND TRANSDATE = CURRENT date - 1 DAY
```

---

Comment: What's the type of `ACT_DURATION`?  If it's character, have you checked it for problem values?  What is the current culture of the session?  Why are you calling `DECIMAL` twice?  You're only widening the top end, which shouldn't effect the end result.  For that matter, you can combine the multiplication and division, too.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Where is DECFLOAT coming from if the query only says DECIMAL (ie. Packed decimal format)

Comment: In recent DB2 versions if you attempt arithmetic operations on string operands they are implicitly cast to `DECFLOAT`. I guess the query optimizer removes the redundant explicit casts in this case. This should be evident in the rewritten query text as shown by `db2exfmt`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in your case expression.
A single result column cannot be numeric for some rows and character in others.

```
SELECT 
    MSISDN,
    CONTRNO,
    TRANSDATE,
    TARIFF_GROUP,
    ACT_DURATION,
    BILLTEXT,
    GROSS_AMOUNT,
    CASE
        WHEN TARIFF_GROUP = 'PAG2'
        THEN DECIMAL(ACT_DURATION * 0.001, 10,4)
        ELSE null
    END RA_RATE
  FROM HISTCALLS
  WHERE call_type IN (50, 54)
    AND TRANSDATE = CURRENT date - 1 DAY
```

Comment: Exactly The solution.. thanks a lot.. Its that A Number Column just cannot hold a Numeric and Varchar value at the same time worked fine when I replaced 'Check' with -999...